# Shoot the Messenger pt. 2

Tags: c#

This is a follow up to [Messenger supporting notifications and requests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71015/messenger-supporting-notifications-and-requests)

> I've written a lightweight (I think) class that acts as a messenger service between classes for both notifications (fire and forget updates to other classes) and requests (a notification sent out that expects a returned value).

Since the last question, I have altered the request system to return an `IEnumerable` filled with all the results from all of the registered functions. This allows the caller to pick from the results or operate on all of them, although I imagine typical use will be to call `.Single()` or `.First()`.

I have also removed the default static instance to prevent laziness and poor code practices, and I have removed a pointless cast between `Action` and `Delegate`

I'm looking for a general review here on style, usability, best practices, etc.

Here's the code ([.NET Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uPLmXC))

```
public class Messenger
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The actions
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> actions = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    /// <summary>
    /// The functions
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<Type, Collection<Delegate>> functions = new Dictionary<Type, Collection<Delegate>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Register a function for a request message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> Type of message to receive. </typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="R"> Type of the r. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="request"> The function that fills the request. </param>
    public void Register<T, R>(Func<T, R> request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }

        if (functions.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            functions[typeof(T)].Add(request);
        }
        else
        {
            functions.Add(typeof(T), new Collection<Delegate>()
            {
                request
            });
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register an action for a message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> Type of message to receive. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="action"> The action that happens when the message is received. </param>
    public void Register<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        if (action == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        }

        if (actions.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            actions[typeof(T)] = (Action<T>)Delegate.Combine(actions[typeof(T)], action);
        }
        else
        {
            actions.Add(typeof(T), action);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send a request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> The type of the parameter of the request. </typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="R"> The return type of the request. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="parameter"> The parameter. </param>
    /// <returns> The result of the request. </returns>
    public IEnumerable<R> Request<T, R>(T parameter)
    {
        if (functions.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            var applicableFunctions = functions[typeof(T)].OfType<Func<T, R>>();

            foreach (var function in applicableFunctions)
            {
                yield return function(parameter);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the specified message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> The type of message. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="message"> The message. </param>
    public void Send<T>(T message)
    {
        if (actions.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            ((Action<T>)actions[typeof(T)])(message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unregister a request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> The type of request to unregister. </typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="R"> The return type of the request. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="request"> The request to unregister. </param>
    public void Unregister<T, R>(Func<T, R> request)
    {
        if (functions.ContainsKey(typeof(T)) && functions[typeof(T)].Contains(request))
        {
            functions[typeof(T)].Remove(request);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unregister an action.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> The type of message. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="action"> The action to unregister. </param>
    public void Unregister<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        if (actions.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            actions[typeof(T)] = Delegate.Remove(actions[typeof(T)], action);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public class Receiver
{
    public Receiver(Messenger messenger)
    {
        messenger.Register<string>(x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            });

        messenger.Register<string, string>(x =>
            {
                if (x == "hello")
                {
                    return "world";
                }
                return "who are you?";
            });

        messenger.Register<string, string>(x =>
        {
            if (x == "world")
            {
                return "hello";
            }
            return "what are you?";
        });
    }
}

public class Sender
{
    public Sender(Messenger messenger)
    {
        messenger.Send<string>("Hello world!");

        Console.WriteLine("");

        foreach (string result in messenger.Request<string, string>("hello"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");

        foreach (string result in messenger.Request<string, string>("world"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Good**

- You are following the naming guidelines
- The method and parameternames are well choosen and meaningful

**Improvable**

- XML comments should, if used, be complete e.g `/// <typeparam name="R"> Type of the r. </typeparam>`
- instead of often calling `typeof(T)` call it once and reuse it.
- using early returns removes horizontal spacing
- creation of the `Collection<Delegate>()`

  > ```
  >         functions.Add(typeof(T), new Collection<Delegate>()
  >         {
  >             request
  >         });
  > ```

  this is less readable than this

  ```
   functions.Add(type, new Collection<Delegate>() { request });
  ```

So this

> ```
> public void Register<T, R>(Func<T, R> request)
> {
>     if (request == null)
>     {
>         throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
>     }
>
>     if (functions.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
>     {
>         functions[typeof(T)].Add(request);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         functions.Add(typeof(T), new Collection<Delegate>()
>         {
>             request
>         });
>     }
> }
> ```

will become

```
public void Register<T, R>(Func<T, R> request)
{
    if (request == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
    }

    var type = typeof(T);

    if (functions.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        functions[type].Add(request);
        return;
    }

    functions.Add(type, new Collection<Delegate>() { request });

}
```

or this

> ```
> public IEnumerable<R> Request<T, R>(T parameter)
> {
>     if (functions.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
>     {
>         var applicableFunctions = functions[typeof(T)].OfType<Func<T, R>>();
>
>         foreach (var function in applicableFunctions)
>         {
>             yield return function(parameter);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

will become

```
public IEnumerable<R> Request<T, R>(T parameter)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    if (!functions.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<R>();
    }

    var applicableFunctions = functions[type].OfType<Func<T, R>>();

    foreach (var function in applicableFunctions)
    {
        yield return function(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good points, thank you, although I disagree with the early returns in both cases. In the first case, having both an if and an else shows that both statements are equally likely, in the second case you have a compiler error. You cannot return `Enumerable.Empty<R>` in an iterator and must instead use `yield return`, which does not work with that early return.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of small points:

1) Develop to interfaces

2) Signify intent by marking invariants as `readonly`

```
/// <summary>
/// The actions
/// </summary>
private readonly IDictionary<Type, Delegate> actions = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

/// <summary>
/// The functions
/// </summary>
private readonly IDictionary<Type, ICollection<Delegate>> functions = new Dictionary<Type, ICollection<Delegate>>();
```