# Shoot The Messenger Part 4

Tags: c#

This is a follow up of:

- [Messenger supporting notifications and requests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71015/messenger-supporting-notifications-and-requests)
- [Shoot the Messenger pt. 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71413/shoot-the-messenger-pt-2)
- [Shoot the Messenger Part 3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73838/shoot-the-messenger-part-3)

> I've written a lightweight (I think) class that acts as a messenger
>   service between classes for both notifications (fire and forget
>   updates to other classes) and requests (a notification sent out that
>   expects a returned value).

I've split the `Messenger` and `Requester` functionality into two separate classes. I'm leaving off the dragon of thread-safety until the next time, for now I'd like to make sure what I have is ok, before worrying about multi-threading.

**Messenger**

```
/// <summary>
/// Strongly-typed messenger system.
/// </summary>
public class Messenger : IMessenger
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The actions. These are called when a message is sent.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, Delegate> actions = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Register an action for a message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> Type of message to receive. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="action"> The action that is executed when the message is received. </param>
    public void Register<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        if (action == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        }

        var messageType = typeof(T);

        if (actions.ContainsKey(messageType))
        {
            actions[messageType] = Delegate.Combine(actions[messageType], action);
        }
        else
        {
            actions.Add(messageType, action);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the specified message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> The type of message. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="message"> The message to send. </param>
    public void Send<T>(T message)
    {
        var messageType = typeof(T);

        if (actions.ContainsKey(messageType))
        {
            ((Action<T>)actions[messageType])(message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unregister an action.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> The type of message. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="action"> The action to unregister. </param>
    public void Unregister<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        var messageType = typeof(T);

        if (actions.ContainsKey(messageType))
        {
            actions[messageType] = (Action<T>)Delegate.Remove(actions[messageType], action);
        }
    }
}
```

**Requester**

```
/// <summary>
/// Strongly-typed request system.
/// </summary>
public class Requester : IRequester
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The functions. These are called when a request is sent.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, ICollection<Delegate>> functions = new Dictionary<Type, ICollection<Delegate>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Register a function for a request message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Request messages have a return value.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> Type of request to receive. </typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="R"> Return type of the request. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="request"> The function that fulfils the request. </param>
    public void Register<T, R>(Func<T, R> request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }

        var requestType = typeof(T);

        if (functions.ContainsKey(requestType))
        {
            functions[requestType].Add(request);
        }
        else
        {
            functions.Add(requestType, new Collection<Delegate>() { request });
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send a request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of request being sent.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="R">Return type of the request.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="parameter">The parameter for the request.</param>
    /// <returns> The results from the request. </returns>
    public IEnumerable<R> Request<T, R>(T parameter)
    {
        var requestType = typeof(T);

        if (functions.ContainsKey(requestType))
        {
            var applicableFunctions = functions[requestType].OfType<Func<T, R>>();

            foreach (var function in applicableFunctions)
            {
                yield return function(parameter);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unregister from a request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> The type of request to unregister from. </typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="R"> The return type of the request to unregister from. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="request"> The request to unregister. </param>
    public void Unregister<T, R>(Func<T, R> request)
    {
        var requestType = typeof(T);

        if (functions.ContainsKey(requestType) && functions[requestType].Contains(request))
        {
            functions[requestType].Remove(request);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MSDN documentation for `Delegate.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A new delegate with an invocation list formed by taking the invocation list of source and removing the last occurrence of the invocation list of value, if the invocation list of value is found within the invocation list of source. Returns source if value is null or if the invocation list of value is not found within the invocation list of source. **Returns a null reference if the invocation list of value is equal to the invocation list of source or if source is a null reference.**

**Emphasize** is mine.

The following unit test fails (see also [here](http://ideone.com/85kzXX) for simplified example):

```
public void UnsubscribingAllShouldNotThrow()
{
    Messenger m = new Messenger();
    var sum = 0;
    Action<int> messenger = x => sum += x;
    m.Register<int>(messenger);
    m.Send(42);
    m.Unregister<int>(messenger);
    m.Send(23);
    Assert.That(sum, Is.EqualTo(42));
}
```

In addition to this you could simplify your code for adding the delegate:

```
Delegate messageDelegate;

actions.TryGetValue(messageType, out messageDelegate);
actions[messageType] = Delegate.Combine(messageDelegate, action);
```

`TryGet` will set the `out` parameter to `default(T)` if the key doesn't exist which is `null` in this case and `Delegate.Combine(null, delegate)` [is perfectly valid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30cyx32c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Ooh good catch!

Comment: Seconded, probably wouldn't have spotted this until waaaay too late, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There isn't much to pick on, really - code is clean, naming is unambiguous, scopes all have their braces, you're `yield`ing enumerables, comments are useful, and you even have XML documentation everywhere... I can't find anything in the code itself that's off-putting, confusing, or just wrong. Nothing.

Except perhaps this:

```
/// <summary>
/// The actions. These are called when a message is sent.
/// </summary>
private readonly IDictionary<Type, Delegate> actions = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();
```

XML comments don't quite belong on private fields (XML documentation is for the public API, right?), I think this should be a regular comment.

Now thread safety -wise, there *might* be something to say, like, why not use a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of an `IDictionary`? Coding against abstractions is great, but sometimes you *do* need a specific implementation ;)

Answer (score 4):

You may want to consider using TryGetValue over ContainsKey/this[index].

```
public void Register<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    if (action == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
    }

    var messageType = typeof(T);

    Delegate messageDelegate;

    if (actions.TryGetValue(messageType, out messageDelegate))
    {
        actions[messageType] = Delegate.Combine(messageDelegate, action);
    }
    else
    {
        actions.Add(messageType, action);
    }
}

public void Send<T>(T message)
{
    var messageType = typeof(T);

    Delegate messageDelegate;

    if (actions.TryGetValue(messageType, out messageDelegate))
    {
        ((Action<T>)messageDelegate)(message);
    }
}
```

...and so on.  It is not necessarily cleaner, but it is a little more correct for the object, and it uses fewer dictionary look-ups.